# Join two tables using entity framework and linq in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to combine two tables in c# for orderManagement.where "SalesOrderDetails" table returns [query results 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvKxl.png) comma seperated product code and quantity

[query results 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDkeL.png)

"SalesOrder" table return order detail.
I have Written stored procedure

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_GetAllOrders] 
AS
BEGIN


SELECT
    SalesOrder.OrderDate,
    SalesOrder.OrderTitle,
    SalesOrder.OrderPriority,
    Customer.Lname,
    Customer.Fname,
    OrderType.OrderTypeName,
    (
        SELECT
            CAST( ProductCode AS varchar ) + ':' + CAST( Quantity AS varchar ) + ','
        FROM
            SalesOrderDetails 
        WHERE
            SalesOrderDetails.SalesOrderId = SalesOrder.SalesOrderId
        FOR xml path('')
    ) AS 'Product'
FROM
    SalesOrder
    INNER JOIN Customer ON SalesOrder.CustomerId = Customer.CustomerId
    INNER JOIN OrderType ON SalesOrder.OrderTypeId = OrderType.OrderTypeId

END
```

It gives me perfect output.same output I want without using stored procedure.
I want same output using entity framework,linq and c# asp.net.I am stuck here

this is what i have tried

TrainingDemoEntities entity = new TrainingDemoEntities();

```
    var details = (from order in entity.SalesOrders
                   join cust in entity.Customers
                   on order.CustomerId equals cust.CustomerId
                   join ordertypevalue in entity.OrderTypes
                       on order.OrderTypeId equals ordertypevalue.OrderTypeId
                   select new
                   {
                       orderId = order.SalesOrderId,
                       orderDate = order.OrderDate,
                       orderTitle = order.OrderTitle,
                       orderPriority = order.OrderPriority,
                       orderType = order.OrderType,
                       productstr = string.Join(",", (from prod in entity.SalesOrderDetails
                                                      where prod.SalesOrderId == order.SalesOrderId
                                                      select prod.ProductCode + ":" + prod.Quantity))
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: You should look up some sample joins using LINQ and try it first, and show us what you've accomplished. You can't just come here and ask for code.

Comment: I am not just asking for code.I have tried many different ways @Armin

Comment: Does your database have a foreign-key relationship set-up? Is EF making use of this relationship? It would be inefficient if it was evaluating the join on your computer instead of doing it in SQL.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've done LINQ. What I'm understanding is the problem is the comma separated list. Can't you use two separate queries and join the results after?

Comment: You shouldn't generate a CSV inside SQL, because that's crossing-concerns (data retreival and presentation): the SQL (or Linq) should only be concerned with getting the raw data, only subsequent C# code should be converting it to a CSV representation.

Comment: Also, correlated-subqueries (a `SELECT` inside another `SELECT` but not inside a `FROM`) generally run poorly, there's almost always a better solution.

Comment: I think you should try to make a join with sales order details table,  in the sql procedure and the linq query, instead of making subquery.

Comment: *this is what i have tried* OK, but what's the problem? (I think `string.Join` not supported).